# C# Adding to DataGrid control programmatically causes blank columns

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid

This is my first time using the C# DataGrid control (and one of my first c# projects) and I'm having a hard time getting a DataGrid control to populate programmatically. Every time I add a row with my two columns they're both blank.

XAML code

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="resultsDataGrid"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,454,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="199" Width="499">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Url"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="404"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

CS code

```
resultsDataGrid.Items.Add(new object[] { detailsOfFind[0], detailsOfFind[1] });
```

I've been looking at examples and I can see you have to bind to datasets/databases/sources but as I'm adding these programmatically I have no idea how to do that? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid has a property called `AutoGenerateColumns` that defaults to true. That'll automatically create a column for each property with a heading of the property's name. However, because you're using an anonymous type, you don't have property names. That's where your blank columns are coming from.

The solution is to add `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` to your `<DataGrid>` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for you input, but unfortunately that hasn't seem to of worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

XAML Code:

```
<Grid Height="396" Name="grid1" Width="565">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,85,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="541" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,37,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

CS Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add Columns to the dataGrid
            DataGridTextColumn c1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
            c1.Header = "Person ID";
            c1.Binding = new Binding("ID");
            c1.Width = 110;
            dataGrid1.Columns.Add(c1);

            DataGridTextColumn c2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
            c2.Header = "First Name";
            c2.Width = 110;
            c2.Binding = new Binding("FirstName");
            dataGrid1.Columns.Add(c2);

            DataGridTextColumn c3 = new DataGridTextColumn();
            c3.Header = "Last Name";
            c3.Width = 110;
            c3.Binding = new Binding("LastName");
            dataGrid1.Columns.Add(c3);

            // Create the Data
            List<Person> myData = new List<Person>();
            myData.Add(new Person() { ID = 5, FirstName = "Jamie", LastName = "White" });
            myData.Add(new Person() { ID = 10, FirstName = "Mike", LastName = "Smith" });
            myData.Add(new Person() { ID = 25, FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Yang" });

            // Pass the data to the dataGrid
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = myData;

            //// OR

            //dataGrid1.Items.Add(new Person() { ID = 5, FirstName = "Jamie", LastName = "Weir" });
            //dataGrid1.Items.Add(new Person() { ID = 10, FirstName = "Mike", LastName = "Smith" });
            //dataGrid1.Items.Add(new Person() { ID = 25, FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Yang" });

            // Modify a cell
            ((Person)dataGrid1.Items[1]).LastName = "Schmidt";

        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string FirstName { set; get; }
        public string LastName { set; get; }
    }


}
```